# Docker commit doesn't save changes

Tags: save, docker, commit

Yeah, you're right, they are many topics like that. I didn't find a solution for my problem. So give me a chance!

I run a docker container with no defined volumes. So what I want is to commit changes like:

```
docker commit 3a09b2588478 myfantasticimage
docker save myfantasticimage > /tmp/fantasticimagecommit.tar
```

Now I transfer the image via scp to another docker-host an do

```
docker load < /tmp/fantasticimagecommit.tar
```

Starting image and I can't see change I do before commited it.
What's the problem. According to the Dockerfile, no volumes are defined.

Thanks!

**Update**: I've found volumes via `docker inspect`-command

```
"VolumesRW": {
    "/var/lib/": true,
    "/var/log/": true,
    "/var/www/": true
}
```

What could be a workaround? I want do back up every 6 hours a container, so I can restore it on the same or another machine without expended effort.

Comment: The commands you list are correct. If you start the a container from the image after committing do you then see your changes? this will help figure out if it's independent of the save/load

Comment: Can there be volumes defined in the images your Dockerfile is based on? The best way to check whether there are volumes or not is to do `docker inspect 3a09b2588478` - are there entries in Volumes?

Comment: Backup your volumes, not your containers.

Answer (score 2):

"docker commit" cannot save mount volumes' data ~
You should `docker cp` files to the container ~

Answer (score 0):

For Saving and Loading Docker Images in another machine without going through docker hub

use below commands

Let say you have an app.tar file then for saving it with app and tag number. Use below commands

```
docker image save -o app.tar app:3
```

For Loading it use below command

```
docker image load -i app.tar
```